# Passing through values with nested then statements

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a function which has the following format:

```
this.callPromiseFunction1(params)
.then(results1 => {
    if (results1.length > 2) {
        this.callPromiseFunction2(params)
        .then(results2 => {
            return results2.stuff;
        }).catch(reject);
    } else {
        return results1.stuff;
    }
})
.then(results3 => {
    this.callPromiseFunction3(someotherparams)
    //do stuff
}).catch(reject)
```

My issue is that if I enter the conditional and call a promise within the first `then()` statement, I get a timing issue and results3 is undefined. Results3 is defined if I enter the `else` statement of the first `then()` statement.

How do I fix this timing issue and allow nested `then()` statements and promises without completely rewriting my promises and forcing them to work together? Is there a way to force the promise to complete in the then statement before continuing to the next `then()`?

Comment: You just need to return the promise in the if statement.

Comment: Do you mean calling `return callPromiseFunction2(params)`? Would I still return within that and keep the return results2.stuff or is there reformatting to be done? Seems to work by just adding the `return` but I don't want to miss any edge cases due to weird async behavior

Comment: @AdamS, yes, that is the correct `return` you added. And you still need to say `return results2.stuff;` as well.

Comment: Thanks @Vic! I feel silly now for being stuck on this for so long. Appreciate the help

Comment: Let me just note that you can't return from an outer function from within an arrow function.  You're just returning from the arrow function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix that problem by returning the promise.  If you notice, in the case in which the if statement of your code executes, you don't return anything.  Returning the promise will cause it to get inserted before the next link in the promise chain.  Also, you don't need the `catch` on that since the last `catch` at the very end will handle that.  Also it's a nice idea to do an early return.  This is what your code could look like:

```
this.callPromiseFunction1(params)
  .then(results1 => {
    if(results1.length <= 2) return results1.stuff;
    return this.callPromiseFunction2(params)
      .then(results2 => results2.stuff);
  })
  .then(results3 => {
    this.callPromiseFunction3(someotherparams)
    //do stuff
  })
  .catch(reject);
```